# Win 7 - cannot login if wifi is turned on

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

I am having a very strange error on my Win 7 Ultimate 64bit system. It's installed on laptop HP Pavilion G6.

Namely, I restart the system and come to the login screen (the system has 4 users). If the **wifi is turned on** (it always is) then I get stack on Logging screen. The only solution is to restart the system.

As from the first time I god this annoyance, I can login only if I **disable wifi and then login**. When I enable wifi after logging to user's desktop, I have no issues as of then.

Anyone has issue like this? I have this one first time in my life and I am advanced user.

Anyone knows any solution besides reinstalling Win7?

**EDIT**

To explain more.

So I come to the login screen, pick any user and press login. And then I am stuck on the Welcome screen. I cannot revert back to login screen (I have shortcut ctrl+alt+l for this). I can stay 30min in this screen and still will not see my desktop. all I can do if force shutdown laptop. This did not happen when I installed the system but in time - did not have such error for 1 year of using the system.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "get stack on Logging screen?"  I assume you enter the username and password, and then click login or press enter, and the system freezes at this point?  What's displayed on the screen then?  Login screen?  Start screen?  Desktop?  Something else?  Can you still move the mouse?  Do you get input buffer beeps if you keep typing?  After rebooting, does the Event Viewer log indicate anything about the previous session?

Comment: Wild stab in the dark, but it is *plausible* that the wifi software (if not just the straight MS off the disk drivers) is using profiles with a per-user scheme and since you aren't logged in completely, it hangs because it doesn't have permissions.

Comment: Uninstall all wifi software and only install the device drivers for the device this means allowing windows to manage your wifi profiles

Comment: @ernie Edited the question

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean? I only have 1 driver for wifi. No extra wifi software. As I said, it worked well for 1 year or so.

Comment: Booting into safe mode would also be a good way to see if this is likely a software/driver issue . . .

Comment: @ernie I can boot to the safe mode with no issues.

Comment: If you can boot in safe mode that indicates a driver problem.

Comment: I SOLVED it by disabling ALL network drivers (inluding Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter) and left only my wifi driver. I can log now without having to disable wifi. Thanks guys for tips.